# All possible combinations in a binary image

Tags: python, arrays, binary, combinations

I'm trying to create all possible combinations of 0 and 1 in an array that have the shape (n, 10). For example, if we assume an arbitrary combination like this: np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]), how can I generate all possible combinations (which will result in 2^10=1024 arrays)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `itertools.product()` with the `repeat` parameter to generate the desired output:

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

np.array(list(product([0, 1], repeat=10)))
```

This outputs:

```py
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 1 0]
 ...
 [1 1 1 ... 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 ... 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `permutations` from the `itertools` module:

```
import numpy as np 
import itertools

list = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
combs = itertools.permutations(list)

for i in combs:
    print(i)
```

Comment: It gives only one.

Comment: I initially misunderstood, now see the edited answer.